# Taking Specific Data from a String in PHP

Tags: php, html

instructions: modify the code below so it prints the following

```
CS 116 01 amulahuw
CS 116 01 amukher1
CS 116 01 amukher1
CS 116 02 amukher1
CS 116 02 gpcorser
CS 116 02 gpcorser
```

I am having problem printing the username(amulahuw,amukher1..etc)

```
<?php



$jsonString = '{"courses":[{"academicLevel":"UG","capacity":"28","comments":[],"courseNumber":"116","credit":"4","description":"This course presents an introduction to the concepts and techniques of computer programming. Emphasis is placed on developing the students ability to apply problem-solving strategies to design algorithms and to implement these algorithms in the Java Programming language.","instructors":[{"username":"amulahuw","name":"A. Mulahuwaish"}],"lineNumber":"0624","location":"UC","meetingTimes":[{"method":"LEC","building":"SE","room":"135","days":"MW","startTime":"10:30 AM","endTime":"12:20 PM","dates":"08\/26\/2019-12\/07\/2019","instructor":"amulahuw"},{"method":"FNL","building":"SE","room":"135","days":"M","startTime":"10:30 AM","endTime":"12:20 PM","dates":"12\/08\/2019-12\/14\/2019"}],"prefix":"CS","prerequisites":"MATH 103 or equivalent (Previous, Required) CS 105 (Previous, Required)  ","seatsAvailable":"4","section":"01","status":"Open","term":"19\/FA","title":"Computer Programming I"},{"academicLevel":"UG","capacity":"30","comments":[],"courseNumber":"116","credit":"4","description":"This course presents an introduction to the concepts and techniques of computer programming. Emphasis is placed on developing the students ability to apply problem-solving strategies to design algorithms and to implement these algorithms in the Java Programming language.","instructors":[{"username":"amukher1","name":"A. Mukherjee"}],"lineNumber":"0610","location":"UC","meetingTimes":[{"method":"LEC","building":"SE","room":"145","days":"TR","startTime":"08:30 AM","endTime":"10:20 AM","dates":"01\/14\/2019-04\/27\/2019","instructor":"amukher1"},{"method":"FNL","building":"SE","room":"145","days":"T","startTime":"08:30 AM","endTime":"10:20 AM","dates":"04\/29\/2019-05\/04\/2019"}],"prefix":"CS","prerequisites":"MATH 103 or equivalent (Previous, Required) CS 105 (Previous, Required)  ","seatsAvailable":"7","section":"01","status":"Open","term":"19\/WI","title":"Computer Programming I"},{"academicLevel":"UG","capacity":"29","comments":[],"courseNumber":"116","credit":"4","description":"This course presents an introduction to the concepts and techniques of computer programming. Emphasis is placed on developing the students ability to apply problem-solving strategies to design algorithms and to implement these algorithms in the Java Programming language.","instructors":[{"username":"amukher1","name":"A. Mukherjee"}],"lineNumber":"0590","location":"UC","meetingTimes":[{"method":"LEC","building":"SE","room":"145","days":"TR","startTime":"08:30 AM","endTime":"10:20 AM","dates":"01\/13\/2020-05\/02\/2020","instructor":"amukher1"}],"prefix":"CS","prerequisites":"MATH 103 or equivalent (Previous, Required) CS 105 (Previous, Required)  ","seatsAvailable":"4","section":"01","status":"Open","term":"20\/WI","title":"Computer Programming I"},{"academicLevel":"UG","capacity":"28","comments":[],"courseNumber":"116","credit":"4","description":"This course presents an introduction to the concepts and techniques of computer programming. Emphasis is placed on developing the students ability to apply problem-solving strategies to design algorithms and to implement these algorithms in the Java Programming language.","instructors":[{"username":"amukher1","name":"A. Mukherjee"}],"lineNumber":"0626","location":"UC","meetingTimes":[{"method":"LEC","building":"SE","room":"145","days":"TR","startTime":"08:30 AM","endTime":"10:20 AM","dates":"08\/26\/2019-12\/07\/2019","instructor":"amukher1"},{"method":"FNL","building":"SE","room":"145","days":"T","startTime":"08:30 AM","endTime":"10:20 AM","dates":"12\/08\/2019-12\/14\/2019"}],"prefix":"CS","prerequisites":"MATH 103 or equivalent (Previous, Required) CS 105 (Previous, Required)  ","seatsAvailable":"10","section":"02","status":"Open","term":"19\/FA","title":"Computer Programming I"},{"academicLevel":"UG","capacity":"30","comments":[],"courseNumber":"116","credit":"4","description":"This course presents an introduction to the concepts and techniques of computer programming. Emphasis is placed on developing the students ability to apply problem-solving strategies to design algorithms and to implement these algorithms in the Java Programming language.","instructors":[{"username":"gpcorser","name":"G. Corser"}],"lineNumber":"0612","location":"UC","meetingTimes":[{"method":"LEC","building":"SE","room":"145","days":"MW","startTime":"12:30 PM","endTime":"02:20 PM","dates":"01\/14\/2019-04\/27\/2019","instructor":"gpcorser"},{"method":"FNL","building":"SE","room":"145","days":"M","startTime":"12:30 PM","endTime":"02:20 PM","dates":"04\/29\/2019-05\/04\/2019"}],"prefix":"CS","prerequisites":"MATH 103 or equivalent (Previous, Required) CS 105 (Previous, Required)  ","seatsAvailable":"5","section":"02","status":"Open","term":"19\/WI","title":"Computer Programming I"},{"academicLevel":"UG","capacity":"29","comments":[],"courseNumber":"116","credit":"4","description":"This course presents an introduction to the concepts and techniques of computer programming. Emphasis is placed on developing the students ability to apply problem-solving strategies to design algorithms and to implement these algorithms in the Java Programming language.","instructors":[{"username":"gpcorser","name":"G. Corser"}],"lineNumber":"0592","location":"UC","meetingTimes":[{"method":"LEC","building":"SE","room":"145","days":"MW","startTime":"12:30 PM","endTime":"02:20 PM","dates":"01\/13\/2020-05\/02\/2020","instructor":"gpcorser"}],"prefix":"CS","prerequisites":"MATH 103 or equivalent (Previous, Required) CS 105 (Previous, Required)  ","seatsAvailable":"0","section":"02","status":"Clsd","term":"20\/WI","title":"Computer Programming I"}]}';

$obj = json_decode($jsonString);

foreach ($obj->courses as $course) {
  echo $course->prefix . " " . $course->courseNumber . " " . $course->section . " " . $course->username . "\n" ;
}
```

I am expecting it to give me the usernames in the data, but instead there is no error message and it dont give me anything.

---

Beautified JSON:

```
{
  "courses": [
    {
      "academicLevel": "UG",
      "capacity": "28",
      "comments": [],
      "courseNumber": "116",
      "credit": "4",
      "description": "This course presents an introduction to the concepts and techniques of computer programming. Emphasis is placed on developing the students ability to apply problem-solving strategies to design algorithms and to implement these algorithms in the Java Programming language.",
      "instructors": [
        {
          "username": "amulahuw",
          "name": "A. Mulahuwaish"
        }
      ],
      "lineNumber": "0624",
      "location": "UC",
      "meetingTimes": [
        {
          "method": "LEC",
          "building": "SE",
          "room": "135",
          "days": "MW",
          "startTime": "10:30 AM",
          "endTime": "12:20 PM",
          "dates": "08/26/2019-12/07/2019",
          "instructor": "amulahuw"
        },
        {
          "method": "FNL",
          "building": "SE",
          "room": "135",
          "days": "M",
          "startTime": "10:30 AM",
          "endTime": "12:20 PM",
          "dates": "12/08/2019-12/14/2019"
        }
      ],
      "prefix": "CS",
      "prerequisites": "MATH 103 or equivalent (Previous, Required) CS 105 (Previous, Required)  ",
      "seatsAvailable": "4",
      "section": "01",
      "status": "Open",
      "term": "19/FA",
      "title": "Computer Programming I"
    },
    {
      "academicLevel": "UG",
      "capacity": "30",
      "comments": [],
      "courseNumber": "116",
      "credit": "4",
      "description": "This course presents an introduction to the concepts and techniques of computer programming. Emphasis is placed on developing the students ability to apply problem-solving strategies to design algorithms and to implement these algorithms in the Java Programming language.",
      "instructors": [
        {
          "username": "amukher1",
          "name": "A. Mukherjee"
        }
      ],
      "lineNumber": "0610",
      "location": "UC",
      "meetingTimes": [
        {
          "method": "LEC",
          "building": "SE",
          "room": "145",
          "days": "TR",
          "startTime": "08:30 AM",
          "endTime": "10:20 AM",
          "dates": "01/14/2019-04/27/2019",
          "instructor": "amukher1"
        },
        {
          "method": "FNL",
          "building": "SE",
          "room": "145",
          "days": "T",
          "startTime": "08:30 AM",
          "endTime": "10:20 AM",
          "dates": "04/29/2019-05/04/2019"
        }
      ],
      "prefix": "CS",
      "prerequisites": "MATH 103 or equivalent (Previous, Required) CS 105 (Previous, Required)  ",
      "seatsAvailable": "7",
      "section": "01",
      "status": "Open",
      "term": "19/WI",
      "title": "Computer Programming I"
    },
    {
      "academicLevel": "UG",
      "capacity": "29",
      "comments": [],
      "courseNumber": "116",
      "credit": "4",
      "description": "This course presents an introduction to the concepts and techniques of computer programming. Emphasis is placed on developing the students ability to apply problem-solving strategies to design algorithms and to implement these algorithms in the Java Programming language.",
      "instructors": [
        {
          "username": "amukher1",
          "name": "A. Mukherjee"
        }
      ],
      "lineNumber": "0590",
      "location": "UC",
      "meetingTimes": [
        {
          "method": "LEC",
          "building": "SE",
          "room": "145",
          "days": "TR",
          "startTime": "08:30 AM",
          "endTime": "10:20 AM",
          "dates": "01/13/2020-05/02/2020",
          "instructor": "amukher1"
        }
      ],
      "prefix": "CS",
      "prerequisites": "MATH 103 or equivalent (Previous, Required) CS 105 (Previous, Required)  ",
      "seatsAvailable": "4",
      "section": "01",
      "status": "Open",
      "term": "20/WI",
      "title": "Computer Programming I"
    },
    {
      "academicLevel": "UG",
      "capacity": "28",
      "comments": [],
      "courseNumber": "116",
      "credit": "4",
      "description": "This course presents an introduction to the concepts and techniques of computer programming. Emphasis is placed on developing the students ability to apply problem-solving strategies to design algorithms and to implement these algorithms in the Java Programming language.",
      "instructors": [
        {
          "username": "amukher1",
          "name": "A. Mukherjee"
        }
      ],
      "lineNumber": "0626",
      "location": "UC",
      "meetingTimes": [
        {
          "method": "LEC",
          "building": "SE",
          "room": "145",
          "days": "TR",
          "startTime": "08:30 AM",
          "endTime": "10:20 AM",
          "dates": "08/26/2019-12/07/2019",
          "instructor": "amukher1"
        },
        {
          "method": "FNL",
          "building": "SE",
          "room": "145",
          "days": "T",
          "startTime": "08:30 AM",
          "endTime": "10:20 AM",
          "dates": "12/08/2019-12/14/2019"
        }
      ],
      "prefix": "CS",
      "prerequisites": "MATH 103 or equivalent (Previous, Required) CS 105 (Previous, Required)  ",
      "seatsAvailable": "10",
      "section": "02",
      "status": "Open",
      "term": "19/FA",
      "title": "Computer Programming I"
    },
    {
      "academicLevel": "UG",
      "capacity": "30",
      "comments": [],
      "courseNumber": "116",
      "credit": "4",
      "description": "This course presents an introduction to the concepts and techniques of computer programming. Emphasis is placed on developing the students ability to apply problem-solving strategies to design algorithms and to implement these algorithms in the Java Programming language.",
      "instructors": [
        {
          "username": "gpcorser",
          "name": "G. Corser"
        }
      ],
      "lineNumber": "0612",
      "location": "UC",
      "meetingTimes": [
        {
          "method": "LEC",
          "building": "SE",
          "room": "145",
          "days": "MW",
          "startTime": "12:30 PM",
          "endTime": "02:20 PM",
          "dates": "01/14/2019-04/27/2019",
          "instructor": "gpcorser"
        },
        {
          "method": "FNL",
          "building": "SE",
          "room": "145",
          "days": "M",
          "startTime": "12:30 PM",
          "endTime": "02:20 PM",
          "dates": "04/29/2019-05/04/2019"
        }
      ],
      "prefix": "CS",
      "prerequisites": "MATH 103 or equivalent (Previous, Required) CS 105 (Previous, Required)  ",
      "seatsAvailable": "5",
      "section": "02",
      "status": "Open",
      "term": "19/WI",
      "title": "Computer Programming I"
    },
    {
      "academicLevel": "UG",
      "capacity": "29",
      "comments": [],
      "courseNumber": "116",
      "credit": "4",
      "description": "This course presents an introduction to the concepts and techniques of computer programming. Emphasis is placed on developing the students ability to apply problem-solving strategies to design algorithms and to implement these algorithms in the Java Programming language.",
      "instructors": [
        {
          "username": "gpcorser",
          "name": "G. Corser"
        }
      ],
      "lineNumber": "0592",
      "location": "UC",
      "meetingTimes": [
        {
          "method": "LEC",
          "building": "SE",
          "room": "145",
          "days": "MW",
          "startTime": "12:30 PM",
          "endTime": "02:20 PM",
          "dates": "01/13/2020-05/02/2020",
          "instructor": "gpcorser"
        }
      ],
      "prefix": "CS",
      "prerequisites": "MATH 103 or equivalent (Previous, Required) CS 105 (Previous, Required)  ",
      "seatsAvailable": "0",
      "section": "02",
      "status": "Clsd",
      "term": "20/WI",
      "title": "Computer Programming I"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Trim your long strings to a minimal length for the question like `course desc` for the description, also indent/beautify your json string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran it on PHP fiddle, which gives the error:

```
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined property: stdClass::$username -- at line 7
CS 116 01 
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined property: stdClass::$username -- at line 7
CS 116 01 
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined property: stdClass::$username -- at line 7
CS 116 01 
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined property: stdClass::$username -- at line 7
CS 116 02 
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined property: stdClass::$username -- at line 7
CS 116 02 
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined property: stdClass::$username -- at line 7
CS 116 02
```

I'm not really sure why you didn't get these errors, and I'm not too familiar with PHP -- maybe check your php.ini file for error reporting settings turned off?

`username` is not a property of the course, but of the course instructor. It seems that there is only one instructor per course, so you can replace `$course->username` with `$course->instructors[0]->username`.

Of course, if you are expecting the possibility of multiple usernames, you should loop through them or join them in some way, e.g. using `join(',', array_map(function(instructor) { return instructor->username }, $course->instructors))`. I.e., for a course like this with multiple professors:

```
{
  "academicLevel": "UG",
  "capacity": "28",
  "comments": [],
  "courseNumber": "116",
  // ..
  "instructors": [
    {
      "username": "amulahuw",
      "name": "A. Mulahuwaish"
    },
    {
      "username": "jsmith",
      "name": "J. Smith"
    },
    {
      "username": "bhappy",
      "name": "B. Happy"
    },
  ],
  // ..
}
```

Using this code snippet:

```
foreach ($obj->courses as $course) {
  echo $course->prefix . " "
     . $course->courseNumber . " "
     . $course->section . " "
     . join(',', array_map(function($instructor) {
                   return $instructor->username;
                 },
                 $course->instructors))
     . "\n" ;
}
```

Should give you:

```
CS 116 01 amukher1,jsmith,bhappy
```

---

You were asking about incrementing `instructors[0]` in the comment. If there are multiple professors, you need to increment it, or otherwise loop through the professors (using the `array_map()` and `join()`) is one way to do it. But if you can assume a maximum of one professor per course (as in your JSON sample), you don't need to increment it.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan Lam! Just out of curiosity, at $course->instructors[0]->username , when do we increment instructor[0]? Is it automatically incremented after each loop in PHP?

Comment: @Simplechinese `instructor[0]` means get the first object in the `instructor` array of the class. Therefore, we are only getting the username of the first instructor -- there is no array incrementing if there are not multiple professors for a course. I've edited my answer for the case of multiple professors.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show what happens if there are multiple professors. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Everything works fine, I learn a lot from you! Thank you for your hard work!

Comment: @Simplechinese On the contrary, I just realized some syntax errors when I tried to run my own code, so they should be fixed now. I'm glad I helped! Make sure to click the check mark to show others it helped you!